# How to prevent duplicates between two different sheets on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets, one is sheet1, other is sheet2.

Data in sheet1

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| L |
| M |
| N |
| O |
| P |

Data in sheet2

| Name |
| --- |
| F |
| G |
| D |
| H |
| G |

Here in sheet2, two data is duplicated. One is "D" compared to sheet1, other is "G" in same sheet2.

I want to prevent duplication in both these cases so that whenever I enter new value in sheet 2, it must check both the sheets and reject duplicate entries.

I am using Google Sheet, and using data validation with a custom formula =COUNTIF(sheet1!A2:A&sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!A2)<2

But, it's not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=COUNTIF({sheet1!$A2:$A;sheet2!$A$2:$A},Sheet2!A2)>1
```

With curly brackets you can join the ranges

Comment: It's not working. I tried adding the duplicate, but it won't shows error.

Comment: You right, I've taken >2 from your formula. Try with >1

Comment: >1 0r <1 ? I tried both, but still don't work.